# Tu's Introduction to Manifolds - Definition of *map locally trivial of rank r*

Tags: definition, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I need a clarification about the following definition provided by Tu's Introduction to manifolds in section 12.3

> A surjective smooth map $\pi : E \to M$ of manifolds is said to be *locally trivial of rank $r$* if
>
> (i) each fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$ has the structure of a vector space of dimension $r$
>
> (ii) for each $p \in M$ there are an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a fiber preserving diffeomorphism $\phi : \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times \mathbb{R}^r$ such that for every $q \in U$ the restriction
> $$
> \left. \phi \right|_{\pi^{-1}(q)} : \pi^{-1}(q) \to \left\{ q \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^r
> $$
> is a vector space isomorphism. Such an open set $U$ is called a trivializing open set for $E$ and $\phi$ is called a trivialization of $E$ over $U$.

Isn't (ii) essentially saying that for every $p \in M$ the fiber preserving map is represented by a linear transformation? And every linear transformation is continuous (in finite dimension) and therefore we can smoothly change from a vector space $\pi^{-1}(p)$ and $\pi^{-1}(q)$ if $q \in U$ where $U$ is some appropriate neighborhood of $p$?

Is this what the definition of "locally trivial" is trying to cover?

Comment: Do you know covering spaces?

Comment: No, what are they?

Comment: OK, that would help explain; sorry.  Usually one learns that first before getting into vector bundles, which is a more natural progression.

Comment: I read through the definition of covering space in wikipedia, I understand the definition but I still struggle to get the picture. Covering spaces and vector bundles look very similar anyway (definition wise).

Comment: Yes, a vector bundle is nearly a covering space, it just has continuous fibers instead of discrete, and the fibers have algebraic structure.